# Cocos2dx: Can't access my own sprite file (.png) in the Resources folder

Tags: visual-studio, cocos2d-x

Using Visual Studio 2019, I am trying to create a sprite in `HelloWorld::init()` in `HelloWorldScene.cpp` and therefore need to access `"player.png"` within the Resources folder. However it throws me an exception if I run the game saying the `_player` variable is `nullptr`. This is weird, I have already put `"player.png"` in Resources but it somehow doesn't work.

[image: player.png location]

But if I access `"HelloWorld.png"`, no exception is thrown and the game runs well. So far, I have only seen solutions to this issue for XCode not for Visual Studio 2019. Does anyone know why this happens? Is it the framework's bug or something is wrong with my attempt?

Below is where the exception occurs.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code ... at a quick glance.

What I've seen causing this problem is an empty file, a file with the wrong extension and (in other formats) a file version that was incompatible with the software reading it.

You might try converting it to JPG (and changing the name in the code) to see if this clears up the problem.